# etree xml parsing and deletion

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

How to delete or remove all the entries for server1 including tags ? I tried to use etree remove function but its not helping

```
  <hosts>
    <host instances="" name="*" roles="alpha">
      <tags/>
    </host>
    <host instances="" name="server1" id="alpha,beta">
      <tags>
        <tag app-id="1" instance="1" name="alpha"/>
        <tag app-id="2" instance="2" name="beta"/>
      </tags>
    </host>
    <host instances="" name="server2" id="beta,gama">
      <tags>
        <tag app-id="1" instance="1" name="beta"/>
        <tag app-id="2" instance="2" name="gama"/>
      </tags>
    </host>
</hosts>


def main1(file=outfile):
 tree = et.parse(file)
 root = tree.getroot()
 thingy = root.find('hosts')
 for thing in thingy:
    if "server1" in thing.get('name'):
        root.remove(thing)
        #thingy.remove(thing)
    print thingy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need parent object to remove its child from the HTML/XML.

Use `getparent()` method to get parent and then `remove()` method to remove its chid tag.

**Demo**:

```
>>> import lxml.etree as PARSER
>>> root = PARSER.fromstring(data)
>>> root.xpath("//hosts/host[@name='server1']")
[<Element host at 0xb6d2ce6c>]
>>> a = root.xpath("//hosts/host[@name='server1']")
>>> for i in a:
...    pp = i.getparent()
...    pp.remove(i)
... 
>>> PARSER.tostring(root, method="xml")
```

---

**A.** `find` return `None` Object for following code.

```
>>> thingy = root.find('hosts')
>>> thingy
```

**This should be `thingy = root.find('host')`**

**B.** Use `xpath` method to get target tag.